# Number of permutations without adjacent elements

Tags: combinatorics

You are given a set, $S$, of size $N$.  $S$ contains an element $K$.  How many sequences of length $M$ can I construct from $S$ such that:

1. No two adjacent objects in the sequence are identical
2. The sequence neither starts or ends with $K$.

You can assume that $N \geq 1$ and that $M \geq 1$.

If only rule 1 were true, it is trivial to calculate.  Furthermore, counting the number of sequences that *do* start or end with $K$ appears to have the same complexity as counting the number of sequences without them.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: This should help: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01819761#page-1